# Bash script not work fine

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I need to write bash script to startup oracle DB
some command should run with user-root and some of them with user-oracle

How can I make these code as a bash script code

```
#!/bin/bash

su root
password
rm /var/tmp/.oracle/*

su oracle
lsnrctl start
sqlplus sys as sysdba
startup
```

But after i run this code ,It ask me root password and dont run other commend after su command.

Thanks.

Comment: why not just run the script itself as sudo and remove all su from script

Comment: Try adding `-` between su and the username, as this provide an environment similar to what the user would have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line in a script is a command to execute. If a command reads input, it doesn't normally get it from the script file, it gets it from the script's standard input. If you want it to read from the script, you have to use a here-document:

```
#!/bin/bash

su root <<EOF
password
rm /var/tmp/.oracle/*

su oracle <<EOF1
lsnrctl start
sqlplus sys as sysdba
startup
EOF1
EOF
```

However, I'm not sure this will work with `su`. It probably doesn't read the password from standard input, but forces it to come from the terminal. You probably should be using `sudo`, which you can configure to not require a password for certain users and scripts.

Or if you use `systemd`, you should be able to configure a service startup script.